# how to accsess thired relationship in model laravel

Tags: php, laravel, orm, model

i have three tables, products , discount ,and dicount_products.
the discount table have the discount data, and the discount_products have the id's of the product and the discount tables, to make a connection bettwen them.

in my model products , am trying to accsess the discount throught the relationship table by doing this

```
//the discount relationship table
public function discount_list(){
    return $this->hasOne(Discount_products::class,'product_id','id');
}

//getting the discount throught the discount_list 
public function discount(){
    return $this->discount_list()->discount();
}
```

the Discount_products model

```
  public function discount(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Discounts::class,'discount_id','id');
    }
```

PS: i know i can do this in the controller but am trying to make discount accessble in one step.

Comment: `dicount_products` is a pivot table... You don't make models for pivot tables in Laravel. You have a `Product` table, a `Discount` table, and a `belongsToMany()` relationship between the two. Please read the documentation on a `many-to-many` relationship in Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: correct, Thank you

Comment: No problem! Also, consider renaming to match Laravel's conventions; in Laravel, the convention is for model names to be singular (so `Product` and `Discount`), while the tables are plural (`products` and `discounts`), and the pivot table is alphabetical-singular (`dicount_product`) It'll help Laravel to help you, as it does a lot of things automatically if the conventions are followed. Cheers!

Comment: is this the right steps for this many to one relationship? for me its not many-to-many .because discount can have more than 1 product but 1 product can only have 1 discount ! , i actually followed your advice and laravel took care of everything, now am reciving the right data. but i need to understand if this is correct convention for my case.

Comment: If a product can only have 1 discount, then you'd need a `discount_id` on each `products` row, then `Discount` would have a `hasMany()` relationship to `Product`, and `Product` would have a `belongsTo()` relationship to `Discount`. That doesn't feel right, but I'd have to look at your schema a bit more.